# A Study in Entomophobia

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, music

> When love take make the times love going sad just
>
> Comes you is better you of be get into old
>
> And sing forever can sugarplum darkness nothing eyes better read
>
> In you see afraid boy words play be go who

---

*This italicized text is not a part of the puzzle. I will add additional lines and/or tags hinting at the solution if the puzzle goes unsolved. Good luck!*

Comment: Possibly useful: rot13(Nyy yvarf unir gra jbeqf.)

Comment: That is somewhat relevant - more of a product of the riddle and/or organization choice on my part than a key component of the riddle. Still, it could help point someone in the right direction @ArnaudMortier

Comment: I'm guessing Arnaud Mortier's comment suggests that the three sentences can be arranged into a grid, aligned to one another, perhaps indicating that the sentences should be arranged with each other to make sense

Comment: @nine9 don't want to confirm or deny just yet...

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say that rearranging is _not_ the key to this puzzle. @nine9

Comment: Back to the drawing board! :)

Comment: @Brandon_J I'm pretty sure the sentences have changed since the last time I viewed this puzzle. Is this an additional clue?

Comment: Can't offer much help besides pointing out that both the title and the words lead directly to rot13(gur orngyrf, cnegvphyneyl gur fbatf n qnl va gur yvsr, url whqr naq yrg vg or). But you probably already knew that,

Comment: @NudgeNudge I actually didn't. Couldn't figure out the intended connection between the music tag and insects

Comment: @nine9 it's been answered. I did add another sentence.

Comment: @nine9 thanks for the extra attention! You did see that the question has been answered, right?

Comment: @Brandon_J jip saw it now and that you have accepted it. I would never have found this! Due to my lack in knowledge of Beatles lyrics :p Currently waiting for what seems to be a timeout before I can award the bounty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @NudgeNudge said in the comments:

> the words describe Beatles songs

And in more details:

> The songs: Let it Be, Love is All You Need, Strawberry Fields Forever, Hey Jude and A Day in the Life.
>  When we arrange the words in a table we can see that each column includes every 10th word in each song, starting from the word in the index of the column. The first column starts with the first word in the song and so on.

```
+-------+------+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| 1     | 2    | 3       | 4      | 5         | 6        | 7       | 8     | 9      | 10   |
+-------+------+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| When  | love | take    | make   | the       | times    | love    | going | sad    | just |
| Comes | you  | is      | better | you       | of       | be      | get   | into   | old  |
| And   | sing | forever | can    | sugarplum | darkness | nothing | eyes  | better | read |
| In    | you  | see     | afraid | boy       | words    | play    | be    | go     | who  |
+-------+------+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+------+
```

> **Let it Be (1):**
>  **When** I find myself in times of trouble, Mother Mary **comes** to me Speaking words of wisdom, let it be
>  **And** in my hour of darkness she is standing right **in** front of me...
>
>  **Love Is All You Need (2):**
>  Love, **love**, love Love, love, love Love, love, love There's nothing
>  **you** can do that can't be done Nothing you can **sing** that can't be sung Nothing you can say, but **you** can learn how to play the
>  game
>
>  **Strawberry Fields Forever (3)**
>  Let me **take** you down 'Cause I'm going to
>  Strawberry Fields Nothing **is** real And nothing to get hung about
>  Strawberry Fields **forever**
>
>  **Hey Jude (4):**
>  Hey Jude, don't **make** it bad Take a sad song and make it
>  **better** Remember to let her into your heart Then you **can** start to make it better Hey Jude, don't be **afraid**
>
>  **A Day in the Life (5):**
>  "Dub the mic on **the** piano quite low this Just
>  keeping it like maracas, **you** know You know those old pianos" "Ok,
>  we're on" "**Sugarplum** fairy, sugarplum fairy" I read the news
>  today, oh **boy**
>
>  **Let it be (6):**
>  When I find myself in **times** of trouble, Mother Mary
>  comes to me Speaking words **of** wisdom, let it be And in my hour of
>  **darkness** she is standing right in front of me Speaking **words** of wisdom, let it be Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be
>  Whisper words of wisdom, let it be
>
>  **Love Is All You Need (7):**
>  Love, love, love
>  Love, love, love
>  **Love**, love, love There's nothing you can do that can't **be** done Nothing you can sing that can't be sung
>  **Nothing** you can say, but you can learn how to **play** the game
>
>  **Strawberry Fields Forever (8):**
>  Let me take you down 'Cause I'm **going** to
>  Strawberry Fields Nothing is real And nothing to **get** hung about
>  Strawberry Fields forever Living is easy with **eyes** closed
>  Misunderstanding all you see It's getting hard to **be** someone
>
>  **Hey Jude (9):**
>  Hey Jude, don't make it bad Take a **sad** song and make it
>  better Remember to let her **into** your heart Then you can start to
>  make it **better** Hey Jude, don't be afraid You were made to **go**
>  out and get her
>
>  **A Day in the Life (10)**
>  "Dub the mic on the piano quite low this
>  **Just** keeping it like maracas, you know You know those **old** pianos" "Ok, we're on" "Sugarplum fairy, sugarplum fairy" I **read**
>  the news today, oh boy About a lucky man **who** made the grade

As for the title:

> Entomophobia is the fear of bugs, which clues to The Beatles

Comment: Nice solve! I wasn't sure if this was going to get solved or not, but you did it! P.S. it might be easier to just think in terms of each song contributing a word every five words instead of splitting it up like you did - still correct, of course.